# Bulk Map Update on HERE platform

Tags: here-api

I use a point of sale system that utilizes the HERE API to build maps of my delivery areas.  Recently, I provided my POS provider with an up-to-date parcels list and parcels shapefile and streets center line file from the County GIS department.

Despite providing this pristine data, my POS provider generated delivery maps that STILL do not include the proper streets and addresses.

After much prodding, I learned that my POS provider uses the HERE API to generate its maps.  Thus, it seems that HERE is the problem, not my POS provider.

There is a way to go into the HERE Map Creator and new addresses.  However, I don't have just one address.  I want to provide HERE with the ENTIRE County GIS database to ensure that their service has the most up-to-date maps.

I would call them about this, but they like to hide behind forms and not provide a telephone number.

Any idea how I can reach someone at HERE technologies to help them update entire counties worth of addresses?

Visited their website.  Realized that I could only add single addresses rather than an entire county.

N/A

N/a

Comment: Did you try to upload your data to your geospace in HERE map creator?

Comment: I've tried, but the files are huge and crash my browser.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  I also need someone to confirm that the format of my files will work with HERE.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a free account on developer.here.com and visit our supplier-portal to upload your data:
https://upload.here.com

Our internal team will be able to verify the data, once it’s uploaded. If you can also give your email address, and the name and description of the data you submit to this email address *selfservesupport@here.com*, then our team will verify the data and get back you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to upload the data in the https://upload.here.com/